# React final form- get the actual state to zoom to a dragging element in the form

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, react-typescript, react-final-form, dnd-kit

I'm making a form with dragging boxes. The form was created with react-final-form, to drag elements I'm using- https://dndkit.com, to zoom to element- react-zoom-pan-pinch.

I want to zoom to elements in my form. I added the function:

```
onClick={() => {
          zoomToElement(question.id, 1.5);
      }}
```

it works well If I don't drag the boxes, but after dragging when I'm trying to zoom to an element, it's zooming to the previous place. I'm thinking it's happening because it's zooming to the initial form state.

The form:

```
    <Form
      onSubmit={submit}
      initialValues={initializeQuestions}
      mutators={{ ...arrayMutators }}
      validate={validateQuestions}
          >
            {({ form, handleSubmit, values, pristine }) => {
              return (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <DndContext
                      onDragStart={(e) => {
                          setDragPoint(e.active.id.toString());
                      }}
                      onDragEnd={(e) => {
                        setDragPoint(null);
                        handleDragEnd(e);
                      }}
                    >
                      <TransformWrapper
                      >
                        {({
                          zoomIn,
                          zoomOut,
                          resetTransform,
                          zoomToElement,
                          centerView,
                          setTransform,
                          state,
                          ...rest
                        }) => {
                          zoomPanPinchState = { ...state };
                          zoomToElement = zoomToElement;
                          setTransform = setTransform;
                          return (
                            <>
                              <TransformComponent
                                wrapperStyle={{
                                  width: '100%',
                                  height: '100%',
                                  position: 'absolute',
                                }}
                                contentStyle={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
                              >
                                <FieldArray name="questions">
                                  {({ fields }) => (
                                    <>
                                      {fields.map((name, index) => (
                                        <div  >
                                          <BoxWrapper
                                            id={fields.value[index].id}
                                            name={`questions[${index}]`}
                                          />
                                        </div>
                                      ))}
                                    </>
                                  )}
                                </FieldArray>
                              </TransformComponent>
                      </TransformWrapper>
                    </DndContext>
                </form>
              );
            }}
          </Form>
```